# How do I change NEI to cheat mode?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

When I heard that you could look up recipes and cheat items with Not Enough Items, I downloaded NEI. It worked, and then I got another mod and the all of a sudden NEI still worked, but it was locked in recipe mode only. I tried fixing it by putting it into cheat mode again, but it was still in recipe mode.

I knew the only reason this happened was probably because of a change in the mod. Then I was watching a YouTuber who had the same exact mod as me and NEI was working and not locked in recipe mode for him. I tried redownloading NEI and getting it again but I was still stuck in recipe mode.

How do I get NEI in cheat mode?

Comment: do you mean you cant go into NEI's options menu to switch modes? the button is on the left side of your inventory screen.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is a config option to lock away cheat mode for non-creative worlds. By default, on a survival world, it will not let you turn on cheat mode. I don't remember the exact config, but I'll look for it really quick.

Comment: "do you mean you cant go into NEI's options menu to switch modes"  yes

Comment: Can you please clear up this? This question is hard to understand. It would be easier to understand if the grammar errors were fixed, and it was put into an easier to read format.

Answer (score 13):

This is a config option to lock NEI in Recipe Mode only. It's designed for people (like me) who want to commit to a Survival game, but can't help themselves when it's so easy to cheat in items. This option is on by default when you download NEI.

You can turn this off in the configuration file. Go to the config folder (probably `C:/Users/YourName/AppData/Roaming/.minecraft/config`) and find `NEI.cfg`. Open it with Notepad, and change the line that says `lockmode=0` to `lockmode=-1`. This will unlock the option to switch to cheat mode in the options menu in-game.

If that doesn't work for whatever reason, cheat mode can be manually set by changing the line that says `cheatmode=0` to `cheatmode=2`.

Comment: yaaaaaaay it worked ty

Comment: Awesome, i'm going for some hardcore LP with this modelock enabled. Are there more things one can do to disable cheating? hof.civfanatics.net has something to detect reloads of older saves, i would love to have this for MC.

Answer (score 1):

Just to add to the previous answers:

An element I wasn't aware of was that after setting NEI to cheat mode, you need to enable the Items option, under Utilities. (This applies to the 1.7 pack I'm playing, anyway.)

This is done by left/right clicking the stone block icon on the right.