# NEI will not stop acting like Recipe mode. Help!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I downloaded NEI for Minecraft 1.6.4. For some reason, it will not stop acting like Recipe mode! I don't mean "I cant change it," because I can. But no matter what I do, it seems stuck on Recipe Mode! I tried deleting and then changing the configs, I have tried absolutely everything I can think of. I just want to use the enchant thingy! Can anyone help?

Comment: Dupe, perhaps: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/158709/nei-recipe-mode-only

Comment: So you set the `lockmode=-1`, and changed it to cheat mode, but when you click on an item in NEI to cheat it in, it doesn't work?

Comment: Without clarification, we can't really help you; I cannot reproduce this at all.

Comment: As an extra note: if you play on a multiplayer server and are not op I think it will lock you to recipe mode for that server. Or something along those lines. It's been quite some time since I looked at that.

Answer (score 2):

It will be disabled in the config file.

1. Go to the config folder probably `%appdata%/.minecraft/config`
2. Then find `NEI.cfg` and open it (notepad can do it)
3. Edit the line that says `lockmode=0` to `lockmode=-1`

This should allow you to go in to cheat mode. this config is mainly there for people like me who cant help them self s for spawning lost items in.

Comment: that doesn't work bro. when i do this, and restart my game, log in, and try to get my survival kit, it only shows recipes again (yes i went into the config and changed lockmode to 1 and nothing happened.)

Comment: @19palkia The answer says to use -1, negative one. Did you try that?

Answer (score 2):

I suspect that if this is a mod pack then the settings will be in user mode but the main setting are set in global,

Open the NEI setting by pressing E then click options in the bottom left then click inventory. you will get a screen like this.

[image: NEI Menu]

in the top right there will be a button you need to make sure this says global before making any changes to the settings so that they apply to the game as a whole.

Hope this helps. this is the case with most mod packs.

(Note: If the "W" boxes are ticked, they will override global settings, which can be confusing if you were unaware an override was active, so be sure to check for this as well.)

Comment: +1. In my case, I I had a W on the settings that was overriding the global settings. Removing the W, or changing the world setting worked